# Пример проверки условий у раскрывающегося списка <select> через jQ/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нигде не могу найти пример проверки условий у раскрывающегося списка `select` через jQ/js.
Например:

Если в select выбран первый пункт, то выводит слово `"hello"`.
Можете написать пожалуйста код на примере этого условия.

В качестве `select` используется код:

```
<select name="sex" id="sex">
  <option value="b1"> Женский </option>
  <option value="b2" selected> Мужской </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить выбранное значение в jQuery есть метод `val`:

```
$("#sex").val();
```

Соответственно условия для проверки:

```js
/* Если выбран значение b1 (в данном случае первый пункт) */
if ($("#sex").val() === "b1") {
  alert("Woman");
/* В противном случае */
} else {
  alert("Not woman");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="sex" id="sex">
  <option value="b1"> Женский </option>
  <option value="b2" selected> Мужской </option>
</select>
```

---

Без jQuery (чистый JavaScript) получение выбранного элемента выглядит так:

```
var select = document.getElementById("sex");    
var selectedValue = select.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Если надо именно проверку по номеру индекса, то можете проверять соответствие `e.selectedIndex === 1`.

Comment: Уберите сниппет или сделайте, что бы код работал

Comment: @Yuri Код работает, при условии, что выбран первый пункт на старте страницы.

Comment: Ну теперь это видно. Нужно, что бы начинающие видели это